# Pulling Data from the Database and passing to View - Laravel Basics

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller

Pretty new to Laravel and looking to get a project off the ground, so I'll cut to the chase.  I'm coming over from codeigniter and was hoping for more documentation/examples.

I'm having an issue where my view is coming up blank white.  I turned debug to true but I am not seeing any errors being reported.

Controller:

```
    public function clientHome()
    {
        $data = Contact::orderAsc()->get();
        $data->toarray();
        return View::make('clientes.clientes', $data);
    }
```

Model:

```
class Contact extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'contact';
    public function scopeOrderAsc()
    {
        return $query->orderBy('sort_order', 'asc');
    }
 }
```

I have rows in my db table called 'contact'.  I have to be missing something small.  I went through the code step by step and it is getting caught at the `return $query->orderBy('sort_order', 'asc');` line.  Thoughts?  Also I'm new here so looking forward to contributing in other areas!

Comment: what do you mean by "getting caught". What is the content of $data variable, can you get it?

Comment: Nothing gets returned after that line.  $data is never populated so I can't view it, at least as far as I can see.

Comment: even if debug is set to true, you still need error reporting on for your server. if you don't know how to do this, paste ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of index.php in the public folder

Comment: are you sure you database access config is correct? Also it may be helpful to watch Laravel and web server logs.

Comment: My error reporting is on in XAMPP.  I have other projects in codeigniter that are reporting errors so I was assuming it was a Laravel setting.

Comment: Yes.  I got a return when I popped in `if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName())
{
   echo "conncted sucessfully to database ".DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass `$query` into your scope method:

```
class Contact extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'contact';

    public function scopeOrderAsc($query)
    { //                          ^^^^^^
        $query->orderBy('sort_order', 'asc');
    }
}
```